# Java throws Process exitValue: 127 when running expect script

Tags: java, bash, cygwin, expect

I'm trying a new approach to a hitch I've been stuck on.  Instead of using expect4j for my SSH connection, (I couldn't figure out a way past blocking consumer runs and issues with closures, see past posts for more info on that if you're knowledgeable and feeling saintly,) I'm going to try to use an expect script.  I have a runtime exec coded in to a button.onclick, see below.  Why am I getting a 127 exit value?  I basically just need this expect script to ssh in, run a single set of expect and send, give me the readout, and that's it...

I'm using cygwin.  Not sure if that's relevant to why this isn't working...is my sh-bang line pointing to the right place?  My cygwin install is a full install, all packages, in C:\cygwin.

Why am I getting a 127 exit value instead of a readout from my server, and how do I alleviate this?

```
try
    {            
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process proc = rt.exec( new String [] {"C:\\cygwin\\bin\\bash.exe", "C:\\scripts\\login.exp"});
        InputStream stdin = proc.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(stdin);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String line = null;
        System.out.println("<OUTPUT>");
        while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println(line);
        System.out.println("</OUTPUT>");
        int exitVal = proc.waitFor();            
        System.out.println("Process exitValue: " + exitVal);
    } catch (Throwable t)
      {
        t.printStackTrace();
      }







#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn ssh userid@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx password
match_max 100000
expect "/r/nDestination: "
send -- "xxxxxx\r"
expect eof
```

Comment: And your question is? I don't see an error message here or any other description of what happens when you try this.

Comment: Sorry:  Why am I getting a 127 exit value instead of a readout from my server, and how do I alleviate this?

Comment: Why do you expect bash, as opposed to 'expect', to succeed in running an expect script?

Comment: Why do I see `expect` with `ssh` every day? It hurts my feelings. Use public keys!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you use bash to execute an expect script. You need to use expect to execute an expect script, or bash to execute an expect script by means of a shell commandline (that would be `Process proc = rt.exec( new String [] {"C:\\cygwin\\bin\\bash.exe", "-c", "C:\\scripts\\login.exp"});`, note the `"-c"` which I have inserted) which makes use of the magic shebang at the top of your script. Or better, use only the shebang: `Process proc = rt.exec( new String [] {"C:\\scripts\\login.exp"});`

The exit value of 127 is a special exit value, and tells you "command not found". Which makes sense as you expect script contains many words for which no system binaries or shell builtins exist.

Comment: Do I just point it to C:\\cygwin\\bin?  I don't see an expect.exe anywhere to point to!

Comment: Forgot we're on windows. I don't know how you can employ shebang lines at all on windows. But calling expect directly `Process proc = rt.exec( new String [] {"C:\\cygwin\\bin\\expect.exe", "C:\\scripts\\login.exp"});` should work (make sure the path to expect is correct).

Comment: @JoSo, you should edit your answer according to your last comment.